# How to replace text between quotes in vi

Tags: vim, vi

Say I have this line of code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
```

Is there a command in vi/vim which can instantly delete everything between quotes and position the cursor between them so I can start typing?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Use `ci"`, which means: change what inside the double quotes.

You can also manipulate other text objects in a similar way, e.g.:

- `ci'` - change inside the single quotes
- `ciw` - change inside a word
- `ci(` - change inside parentheses
- `dit` - delete inside an HTML tag, etc.

More about different vim text objects [here](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/10/17/vim-text-objects-the-definitive-guide/).

Comment: Seems only working with `vim`, but NOT `vi`. (Not sure)

Comment: For me this only works on the current line, not anywhere in the document.

Comment: what command then would do this backwards?  That is if you wanted to replace text inside of quotes that is behind the cursor.

Comment: @dtburgess: One way is `F"ci"`.

Comment: ci' and ci" works fine, but ci( does not work for me. Anyone any ideas why?

Comment: @Vram Vardanian `ci(` has a synonym `cib`, maybe it will work

Answer (score 30):

You can select between quotes and then delete (`d`), change (`c`) etc. using

```
vi"
```

Similarly, you can substitute braces, brackets, XML elements etc. thus:

```
vi(
vi{
vit
```

or to simply change/delete, do the corresponding `di"`, `ci"` etc. Substituting `a` for `i` will encompassing the surrounding elements (so you mark or change the brackets *and* contents, for example)

Answer (score 6):

An addition to Brian's answer, you can also `p`(paste) and `y`(yank) the new value, so if you want to replace the value inside quotes with another value, you could do `yi"` on the selection that you want to copy, `vi"` to select the area that you want to replace and then just `p` to properly replace the value.

Comment: thank you. `yi"` is useful for copying text in between quotes.

Answer (score 5):

I've made a plugin `vim-textobj-quotes`: https://github.com/beloglazov/vim-textobj-quotes

It provides text objects for the closest pairs of quotes of any type and supports quotes spanning multiple lines. Using only `iq` or `aq` it allows you to operate on the content of single ('), double ("), or back (`) quotes that currently surround the cursor, are in front of the cursor, or behind (in that order of preference). In other words, it jumps forward or backwards when needed to reach the quotes.

It's easier to understand by looking at examples (the cursor is shown with `|`):

1. Before: `foo '1, |2, 3' bar`; after pressing `diq`: `foo '|' bar`
2. Before: `foo| '1, 2, 3' bar`; after pressing `diq`: `foo '|' bar`
3. Before: `foo '1, 2, 3' |bar`; after pressing `diq`: `foo '|' bar`
4. Before: `foo '1, |2, 3' bar`; after pressing `daq`: `foo | bar`
5. Before: `foo| '1, 2, 3' bar`; after pressing `daq`: `foo | bar`
6. Before: `foo '1, 2, 3' |bar`; after pressing `daq`: `foo | bar`

The examples above are given for single quotes, the plugin works exactly the same way for double (") and back (`) quotes.

You can also use any other operators: `ciq`, `diq`, `yiq`, `viq`, etc.

Please have a look at the github page linked above for more details.

Answer (score 4):

From already inside the quotes you can do

```
di"
```

Read it as delete inside "

Comment: The cursor is not required to be within the double-quoted string, as the command defaults to changing the first such string in the line

Comment: Thanks that's very good to know! Just goes to show I should read things a bit more carefully. :)

Answer (score 2):

The chosen answer is suitable ONLY for ViM but NOT for vi. The question is inaccurate as well because the author did not mention what is initial position of the cursor. If we assume that the cursor is inside the double quotes then for vi the answer will be:

```
T"ct"
```

Where:

T" - move back just after the " character

c - change command

t" - provide end position for c command, where it should stop erasing characters, in other words the range to change