# vim recommended command to replace a word after a symbol

Tags: vim

Question is in the title but an example will explain it better. Suppose I am editing a config file with vim and want to change this line

```
uid = www-data
```

to

```
uid = anotheruser
```

the **ci"** is perfect for me when the value is between quotes ( cf [How to replace text between quotes in vi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630440/how-to-replace-text-between-quotes-in-vi) ) but when it's not I resort to use insert mode (for now). What would you use to get the job done faster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your cursor is somewhere on `www-data`

I would do `T<space>Canotheruser`.

**T{char}** moves the cursor to left until the it is just after the first occurrence of {char}

**C** is a short hand for **c$** which deletes from the cursor to the end of the line and enters insertion mode.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to your <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> when the text is in between quotes you could in this scenario use the WORD text-object.

Putting your cursor somewere inside `www-data` and press <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>

Read more about text-objects by typing `:h text-objects`

But personally I would use also the <kbd>C</kbd> command which changes the text from cursor to the end of the line, as already mentioned by others. Probably something like this `/www<CR>Canotheruser<ESC>`

Answer (score 0):

Use **c$** to delete text to the end of line.

Put cursor on the first `w` of `uid = www-data` and then use **c$**.