# What Vim command(s) can be used to erase strings in double(or single) quotes and go insert mode?

Tags: vim

I have documents that are full of double-quoted sentences. And using editors, It seems likely comfortable when 'erase strings surrounded by double(or single) quotes and go insert-mode' function embedded. Is there any way to do it using with vim?

Comment: Change inside quotes, `ci"` (or `ci'` for single-quoted strings)

Comment: oh, thanks, It's easier than I thought! thanks

Comment: `:help c`, `:help text-objects`, `:help i"`

Comment: The same question has previously been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630440/how-to-replace-text-between-quotes-in-vi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change inside quotes, ci" (or ci' for single-quoted strings)

Comment: thanks for the answer! And I find this way can be extended on using with >, ).